# Colored vertical lines for nested responses of e-mail

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, minipage

In a typical e-mail program, responses to a message are shown with a colored vertical line to the left of the response. Multiple responses are shown in a nested fashion, like this:

[image]

I want to produce something similar using nested environments e.g.,

```
\begin{response}
First response
\begin{response}
Second response
\end{response}
\end{response}
```

Now here is the catch: I want the text to break nicely across page boundaries. Thus I cannot use `\vrule` + `minipage` as I would do otherwise. The giant package `tcolorbox` and the simpler package `framed` allow page breaks, but they do not seem to work for nested boxes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nesting `adjustbox` environments, from package `changepage`?

Comment: The `changepage` package does not seem to have an `adjustbox` environment..?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I meant `adjustwidth`. I would suggest using `framed` inside `adjustwidth` nested environments.

Comment: It does not seem to help, `framed` does not work inside `adjustwidth`. Another frame package, `mdframed` does work inside `adjustwidth`, but without the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way: Nested `breakbox` environments from the package `boites`.